# HashiCorp Vault Enable REST Call

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I am following the [HashiCorp tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-secret-store-driver) and it all looks fine until I try to launch the "webapp" pod - a simple pod whose only function is to demonstrate that it can start and mount a secret volume.

The error (permission denied on a REST call) is shown at the bottom of this command output:

```
kubectl describe pod webapp
Name:             webapp
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  webapp-sa
Node:             docker-desktop/192.168.65.4
Start Time:       Tue, 14 Feb 2023 09:32:07 -0500
Labels:           <none>
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:
IPs:              <none>
Containers:
  webapp:
    Container ID:
    Image:          jweissig/app:0.0.1
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /mnt/secrets-store from secrets-store-inline (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-5b76r (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  secrets-store-inline:
    Type:              CSI (a Container Storage Interface (CSI) volume source)
    Driver:            secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
    FSType:
    ReadOnly:          true
    VolumeAttributes:      secretProviderClass=vault-database
  kube-api-access-5b76r:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    42m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/webapp to docker-desktop
  Warning  FailedMount  20m (x8 over 40m)   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[secrets-store-inline], unattached volumes=[secrets-store-inline kube-api-access-5b76r]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  12m (x23 over 42m)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod default/webapp, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error making mount request: couldn't read secret "db-password": Error making API request.

URL: GET http://vault.default:8200/v1/secret/data/db-pass
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
           * permission denied
  Warning  FailedMount  2m19s (x4 over 38m)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[secrets-store-inline], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-5b76r secrets-store-inline]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

So it seems that this REST call fails: `GET http://vault.default:8200/v1/secret/data/db-pass`. Indeed, it fails from `curl` as well:

```bash
curl -vik -H "X-Vault-Token: root"  http://localhost:8200/v1/secret/data/db-pass
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8200...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8200 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8200: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8200: Connection refused
```

At this point I am a bit lost. I am not sure that the REST call is configured correctly, i.e. in such a way that Vault will accept it; but I am also not sure how to configure it differently.

The Vault logs show the information below, so I seems that the port and token I use are correct:

```
2023-02-14 09:07:14 You may need to set the following environment variables:
2023-02-14 09:07:14     $ export VAULT_ADDR='http://[::]:8200'
2023-02-14 09:07:14 The root token is displayed below
2023-02-14 09:07:14 Root Token: root
```

Vault seems to be running fine in Kubernetes:

```bash
kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
vault-0                                 1/1     Running   1 (22m ago)   32m
vault-agent-injector-77fd4cb69f-mf66p   1/1     Running   1 (22m ago)   32m
```

If I try to show the Vault status:

```bash
vault status
Error checking seal status: Get "http://[::]:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp [::]:8200: connect: connection refused
```

I don't think the Vault is sealed, but if I try to unseal it:

```bash
vault operator unseal
Unseal Key (will be hidden):
Error unsealing: Put "http://[::]:8200/v1/sys/unseal": dial tcp [::]:8200: connect: connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you created proper policy in vault so your client can access the secret saved in vault ?

Comment: @HarshManvar Thank you for your answer! I am new to Vault. However, I can see that Vault seems to be running fine in K8s in Docker, but if I run `vault status`, I get `Error checking seal status: Get "http://[::]:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp [::]:8200: connect: connection refused`. Same if I try curl. So maybe Vault is not set up properly? But I just did what the tutorial asked me to do.

Comment: your vault is sealed first unseal it otherwise you won be able to access any data. try to open the UI of vault with port forward or so you might need to download keys and it will be unsealed for the first time. your vault won't be ready also 0/1 status will be there if checking `kubectl get pods`

Comment: @HarshManvar I don't think the Vault was sealed. I don't know how to access the UI and I don't think I can, since it's running inside K8s in Docker on my PC, and Docker does not show that the Vault app exposes any ports to the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As pertains to the tutorial, it works. Not sure what I was doing wrong, but I ran it all again and it worked. If I had to guess, I would suspect that some of the YAML involved in configuring the pods got malformed (since white space is significant).
2. The `vault status` command works, but only from a terminal running inside the Vault pod. The Kubernetes-in-Docker-on-DockerDesktop cluster does not expose any ports for these pods, so even though I have vault-cli installed on my PC, I cannot use `vault status` from outside the pods.